# Error al borrar item recyclerview

Tags: recyclerview

Estoy intentando crear una lista de elementos con un botón en el `recyclerview` que me elimine el elemento en sí. El problema es que al borrar el *item* de la lista desde el adaptador, si no lo hago desde abajo hacia arriba empieza a descuadrarse y acaba cerrando la aplicación.

He visto algún *post* con problemas parecidos y he intentado las soluciones propuestas pero no lo he conseguido, por ello abro un nuevo *post*.

```
public class AdapterActividades extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterActividades.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener{

    private List<Datos> listaActividades;
    private Context context;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;

    public AdapterActividades(Context context,List<Datos> listaActividades) {
        this.listaActividades = listaActividades;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.actividad, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Datos dato=listaActividades.get(position);
        holder.nombre.setText(dato.getNombre());
        holder.boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listaActividades.remove(position);
                AdapterActividades.this.notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaActividades.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView nombre;
        protected ImageButton boton;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            nombre=v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            boton=v.findViewById(R.id.boton);
        }
    }
}
```

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado el error, lo dejo escrito por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.

He cambiado:

```
listaActividades.remove(position);
AdapterActividades.this.notifyItemChanged(position);
```

por:

```
listaActividades.remove(position);
AdapterActividades.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Saludos

Comment: Buenas kyo! revisa este enlace [Vincular a mi cuenta de usuario una pregunta que hice como invitado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3430/vincular-a-mi-cuenta-de-usuario-una-pregunta-que-hice-como-invitado/3431#3431) para juntar el usuario de tu pregunta con el de la respuesta.l un saludo!